# Error while implementing Solr using solarium

Tags: solr, solarium

I installed solr using the Bitnami installation in windows. When i ping the server using solarium.

If use var_dump($result->getResponse()); then everything works fine but if i use var_dump($result->getdata()); I get a error saying JSON could not be encoded.

Similarly when i try to index data into the solr server i get this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Solarium\Exception\HttpException' with message 'Solr HTTP error: OK (405) Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL<br> HTTP ERROR 405<br> Problem accessing /solr/admin.html. Reason: <br> HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL<br> Powered by Jetty<br> in C:\xampp\htdocs\trial\search\vendor\solarium\solarium\library\Solarium\Core\Query\Result\Result.php on line 104</p> <p>What can be the possible issue?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here

It seems to be an issue related to Solarium, and not with Bitnami Solr. You can see the issue here:
https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/issues/101

You could ask there.

I hope it helps